# Where has the websocket.inject_message method gone?

Tags: python, mitmproxy

In the [docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#websocket-inject-message) it says that I can inject messages to a websocket flow by calling `flow.inject_message` yet when I try that I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'HTTPFlow' object has no attribute 'inject_message`

Looking at github, it seems that method was recently removed in this [PR](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/pull/4422). Has that functionality moved somewhere else or has it been removed entirely? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality has been temporarily removed on master when we shifted to the new [sans-io proxy core](https://mitmproxy.org/posts/new-proxy-core/). I have coincidentally opened a pull request yesterday that brings it back ([#4502](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/pull/4502)). The new API is different, but accomplishes the same:

```python
def websocket_message(flow):
    last_message = flow.websocket.messages[-1]
    if b"secret" in last_message.content:
        last_message.kill()
        ctx.master.commands.call("inject", [flow], not last_message.from_client, "ssssssh")
```